# Chandrasekhar limit with relativistic electron gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, quantum-statistics, fermi-energy

### The problem

In David Tong's [lecture notes on statistical physics](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys/statphys.pdf) (pages 100-102), there's a chapter on [Chandrasekhar limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrasekhar_limit) in relativistic case, where he states that energy degeneracy is
$$g(E)=\frac{V}{\pi^2\hbar^3c^3}\left(E^2-\frac{m^2c^4}{2}+\ldots\right),\tag1$$
from where he obtains that at $T=0$ number of particles and **kinetic** energy are
$$N=\frac{V}{\pi^2\hbar^3c^3}\left(\frac{1}{3}E_F^3-\frac{m^2c^4}{2}E_F+\ldots\right),\tag2$$
$$E_{\mathrm{kinetic}}=\frac{V}{\pi^2\hbar^3c^3}\left(\frac{1}{4}E_F^4-\frac{m^2c^4}{4}E_F^2+\ldots\right).\tag3$$
He then states that the total energy of the system is then given as
$$E_{\textrm{grav}}+E_F=\left[\frac{3\hbar c}{4}\left(\frac{9\pi M^4}{4m_p}\right)^{1/3}-\frac{3}{5}G_N M^2\right]\frac{1}{R}+\mathcal{O}(R)\tag4$$
(I figure that he meant $E_\mathrm{kinetic}$ and not $E_F$ on the left-hand side of the last equation).
**He concludes that the Chandrasekhar limit is possible only when the $1/R$ term is *positive***.

**But**, if you go through the calculations that include the second term in (2), you get that (4) is actually
$$E_{\textrm{grav}}+E_F=\left[\frac{3\hbar c}{4}\left(\frac{9\pi M^4}{4m_p}\right)^{1/3}-\frac{3}{5}G_N M^2\right]\frac{1}{R}-\frac{m^2c^3}{3\pi\hbar}\left(\frac{9\pi M}{4m_p}\right)^{2/3}R\tag5$$
If we write (5) as $E_{\textrm{grav}}+E_F=\frac{A}{R}-B\cdot R$, where obviously $B>0$, we get from the stability condition
$$\frac{\partial(E_{\textrm{grav}}+E_F)}{\partial R}\Biggr\rvert_{R = R_0}=0$$
that $R_0=\sqrt{-\frac{A}{B}}$, which implies that $A$ has to be ***negative*** for the stability to be possible. Am I in the right?

### My rationalization

It seems to me that the dispersion relation that Tong used to derive (1) is
$$\varepsilon_\mathbf{p}=\sqrt{m^2c^4+c^2\mathbf{p}^2},$$ which would be the **total** energy of a particle and not **kinetic** energy of a particle, from which he (presumably) derived (3).

If we instead take the dispersion relation

$$\varepsilon_\mathbf{p}=\sqrt{m^2c^4+c^2\mathbf{p}^2}-mc^2,\tag6$$
we get that energy degeneracy is
$$g(E)=\frac{V}{\pi^2\hbar^3c^3}\left(E^2\;{\large{\boldsymbol{+}}}\; \frac{7}{8}m^2c^4+\ldots\right).\tag7$$
If we from here carry out the derivation of (4), we get that the $R$ term now is positive and Tong's conclusion now stands.

Could you confirm or deny whether my rationalization is correct?

Also, would the satisfactory way of evaluating the Fermi energy $E_F$ of an electron as a function of particle number be finding it from ultra-relativistic limit, i.e. ignoring the second term in (7), and then plugging it back in the first and second term of total kinetic energy? It seems to me that Tong used that method for deriving (4) and I also used it when calculating (4) with different dispersion relation.

Comment: I think you both are saying the same thing. The Chandrasekar limit refers to the stability limit of a star beyond which the star further collapses. Tong says there is no stability when $A > 0$, you found the justification for it.

Comment: @emirsezik Tong states that there is no stability when $A<0$.

Comment: You are right, I apologise. I am currently looking at the notes and prof. Tong may actually have made a mistake and you may be right. Though, in the end, the sign of A doesn't matter as the limit you are searching for is given by A = 0.